# SQLalchemy seems to rewrite previous retrieved datasets

Tags: sqlalchemy

I use Python 3.10, and SQLAlchemy. It looks like a previous variable is being overwritten when new data is written to the database. I do not understand how this is even possible.

I have a piece of code that does the following.

Retrieves data, stores it in a List. Lets say, X.
This variable X now contains [x,y,z]

I then run an update query on the exact table that X was queried for. Lets say with data [w,e,r]
Now when I print out X, it prints [w,e,r], and not [x,y,z]

Here is my code. I moved it out of functions to make it easier to understand, and changed a variable name or two. This is all the code that runs when this variable gets changed.

```
    __ids = []
    original_data = []
    delivery = AStatus(db)

    for values in payload:
        sub = {'A_id': values['A_id'], 'X_id': values['X_id'], }
        __ids.append(sub)

    original_data = delivery.findByAIdAndXId(__ids)
    print(original_data) # The variable prints the correct data

    delivery1 = AStatus(db)

    # Do an update to the data pulled in original_data
    # update_data contains new data that came in.
    # There is no other code between the first print(original_data) and last print(original_data)
    try:
        for value in update_data:
            record = self.db.active_session().query(self.__model).filter_by(A_id=value["A_id"], \
                X_id=value["X_id"]).first()
            if record:
                for changed_field_key, changed_field_value in value.items():
                    if changed_field_key not in ['A_id', 'X_id']:
                        setattr(record, changed_field_key, changed_field_value)
            record.updated_at = datetime.now()

         self.db.active_session().commit()
    except Exception as e:
        self.db.active_session().rollback()
        capture_exception(e)

    # This variable now reflects the new data inserted into the DB, and not the old data anymore
    print(original_data)
```

I do not believe that original_data somehow is in the background linked to the database. I just cannot explain this behaviour.

Comment: I think I got it working, typing the above question made me think. I am now closing the session and opening a new one just after the try block. I can no see what I am expecting.